# return multiple rows using loop or iterator (or other) in postgresql

Tags: sql, function, postgresql

I have a query that uses some hardcoded values to return the difference between two geometries, and I want to be able to run it for multiple values.

```
Select 27, ST_AsKML(ST_SymDifference(a.the_geom ,b.the_geom), 5)
from 
    (select ST_Union(ST_Expand(geom, .0051)) as the_geom
    from temp_grouped_points
    where weight >= 30) as a,
    (select ST_Union(ST_Expand(geom, .0051)) as the_geom
    from temp_grouped_points
    where weight >= 27) as b
```

The important parts here are the values 27 and 30 in the above query.  What I'd like is to have some query that returns multiple rows of integers and KML over some set of multiples of three.  The query above is an example for an integer with value of 27, then presumably the query would run again with 30 (and 33 in the first subquery), and so on.  I don't have a lot of experience with stored procedures / functions, so if that's the easiest solution, any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might come across this issue or wants an example for calling functions within functions, returning multiple rows, etc, my solution is below.

```
    --create a datatype to use to return results
    CREATE TYPE kml_result AS (f1 int, f2 text);

    --create a function that will run a select statement for a given value.  we will call this function in a loop later to get the desired results as multiple rows
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION retrieveKml(value INT, out f2 text)
    AS
    'Select ST_AsKML(ST_SymDifference(a.the_geom ,b.the_geom), 5)
    from 
        (select ST_Union(ST_Expand(geom, .0051)) as the_geom
        from temp_grouped_points
        where weight >= (value + 3)) as a,
        (select ST_Union(ST_Expand(geom, .0051)) as the_geom
        from temp_grouped_points
        where weight >= value) as b'
    LANGUAGE SQL;

    --create a function that will loop over some value, calling the previous function at each step, then adding the first function's return value to the out function's return set  
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dup(value INT) RETURNS setof kml_result AS 
    $$
        DECLARE r text;
        DECLARE i int := value;
            BEGIN
                    WHILE i > 0 LOOP
                SELECT retrieveKml(i) into r;
                return next (i, r);
                i = i - 3;
                    END LOOP;
            END;
    $$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;

    --run the function
    select * from dup(6)
```

result:

```
6;"<MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-87.6552,41.88882 -87.65,41.88882 -87.65,41.89902 -87.655,41.89902 -87.655,41.90382 -87.65,41.90382 -87.65,41.91402 -87.6602,41.91402 -87.6602,41.90902 -87.6652,41.90902 -87.6652,41.89882 -8 (...)"
3;"<MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-87.6452,41.93882 -87.6402,41.93882 -87.635,41.93882 -87.63,41.93882 -87.63,41.93402 -87.63,41.93382 -87.63,41.92902 -87.625,41.92902 -87.625,41.92402 -87.625,41.91902 -87.62,41.91902 -87.62 (...)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, probably because you do not show us a possible set of results. That being said, you may want to create a function, indeed, or maybe two: one to run the query you're showing with a value as you selected, then one to loop and call that function as required.

PostgreSQL functions are created in this way:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html

To test new implementation of your function, use `CREATE OR REPLACE ...` so that way you can update it painlessly.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION retrieve(value INT)
    AS 'SELECT ... WHERE WEIGHT > value ...'
    RETURN INT;
```

Note that your SELECT should return one integer in this example, because you do not need to return the 27 (as shown in your code snippet).

With the documentation you should be able to create the other function to loop over this one.